How to delete comma from within quotation marks
before
aaa,"da,dd",22,22

after
aaa "da dd" 22 22

What is required to be done to get this:?
aaa,"dadd",22,22

Const replaceMe As String = "," '
Const replacement As String = " "

Dim line As String = Nothing
Using r As New StreamReader("s.txt")
    Using w As New StreamWriter("d.txt")
        line = r.ReadLine()
        While Not line Is Nothing
            w.WriteLine(line.Substring(0, 9) + line.Substring(9).Replace(replaceMe, replacement))
            line = r.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Using
End Using

The code above replaces everything in the text file, then saves the file again, but I want to replace only what is inside the quote mark.

replace or delete?'

you could try https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-8.0

Match (".*)(,)(.*") and relace with $1~$3?

replace or delete?' – nbk  I want to exchange

Match (.)(,)(.") and replace with $1~$3?
a,"d,d",22,22
I want to delete comma from within quotation marks

This code replaces each comma from within a text file
I want to replace only what is inside the quotation marks

In your code, you have replacement As String = "~". Is your post incorrect? Removing the comma means that you get, e.g., aaa,"dadd",22,22? If that's the case, then just replace with $1$3

It sounds like you're thinking about this the wrong way, trying to clean up csv data for a later call to a naiive Split() function. Instead, find a real csv parser. A real parser can handle the quoted fields (as well as many other edge cases) gracefully and correctly, usually with much better performance. There are several good csv parsers available via NuGet.

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Const replaceMe As String = ","
Const replacement As String = ""
Dim regEx As New Regex("""([^""]*)""")

Dim line As String = Nothing
Using r As New StreamReader("s.txt")
    Using w As New StreamWriter("d.txt")
        line = r.ReadLine()
        While line IsNot Nothing
            w.WriteLine(regEx.Replace(line, Function(m) _
                m.Value.Replace(replaceMe, replacement)))
            line = r.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Using
End Using


s.txt
aaa,"da,dd",22,22 aaa,"da,dd",22,22 aaa,"da,dd (no closing quotation mark)

d.txt
aaa,"dadd",22,22 aaa,"dadd",22,22 aaa,"da,dd (no closing quotation mark)

